# Methodology for identifying grocery items from a OCR read

Tags: ruby, nlp

I'm writing an Ruby application that reads text off of a grocery store receipt and allows a user to see how much they are paying per ounce and possibly serving based on ingredients.  I'm using the Tesseract gem which was pretty straight forward.  However, the line items are often wrong, sometimes comically so, as in the case of "burly parsley" for "curly parsley".

I assume solving this problem is in some way a natural language processing problem but I don't have the background currently to even know what direction to go in.  My first idea is to hack the ideas of others, make a Google request and if they suggest something different, use that.  However, I'd like to read and learn how this problem might be solved correctly.

So how should I go about solving my burly parsley problem?

Comment: I think this is actually a pretty big problem, if you are talking about solving it in the general case.  For your use case, I'd consider a dictionary of all grocery items.  If the OCR gives you hits that do not match any dictionary items exactly, you can test for very close matches using Levenshtein distance or similar, and if it finds a close match, use that.  If it still finds nothing, just use the orginal and hope it's a new item not yet in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could go about dealing with a problem like this. Here's one off the top of my head:

1. Dictionaries - If you're restricting yourself to a vertical - retail in this case - it should be possible to build a dictionary of all the possible items you could encounter. You could then proceed to compare your results from the OCR read to words in your dictionary using some form of string similarity/matching. I'd written [an article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Algorithms/A_2661-A-Guide-to-Approximate-String-Matching.html) on the subject here a while ago covering approximate string matching techniques. It's a little old but still relevant as it just covers the basics.
2. If you run into an item not existing in your dictionary and not a reasonable approximate match to any of the items there (that is, something entirely new), you could temporarily treat it as a new item for the purposes of the current case, and flag it for review. Your review later can decide whether it's a new item altogether, or just a really bad read. In the first case, you add it to the dictionary and in the second you map it to the original item.

You could also create a data structure that maps variations to the original item. For example, let's take the "burly parsley" case. This would be picked up in step 1 I outlined above to match "curly parsley". Typically, doing a bunch of string approximation comparisons is expensive. To save time the next time you encounter it, you could add "burly parsley" to your list of known variations for an item.

The next time you encounter "burly parsley" you'd see it as a variation of "curly parsley" and pick that without having to spend time doing comparisons again.

Comment: I think I'll combine your suggestions with a request to Google to confirm the item before putting it in the dictionary.  Then for items that are completely new, just add them to an admin page for review or let the user add them on scan.